# blpapi Bloomberg - Python prog. vs. BBG Interaction

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, spyder, bloomberg, blpapi

I'm quite new to Python (Got forced to use it since BBG don't support R), and i'm having difficulty installing blpapi. I'm currently using Spyder and Python 2.7 version.

Does anyone on this forum had already used python to send orders to Bloomberg and manipulate data provided by the terminal? If Positive, could you pls share how you've installed the API Libs and any other useful stuff. The idea is to feed a certain model with live data.

There's an .exe file in the Zip that you download from WAPI , but there's an error message appearing. I've already tried to speak with a BBG represent. but that does not helped.

Regards,

Comment: Read this to post clearer questions - [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Also take the [tour] and learn [ask] - as it stands, this is very "chatty" and a poor fit for SO's Q&A model.

Comment: I see that you can connect to Bloomberg API with R: https://github.com/Rblp/Rblpapi

Answer (score 0):

This was posted a long time ago but I'll answer in case someone else has this question...

Realistically, the easiest way to do it is with Anaconda:

1. Open Anaconda Prompt (as admin)
2. "pip install blpapi" OR "conda install - c concad-forge blpapi"...

Hope this helps.